# Use of comma before coordinating conjunction that starts a dependent clause

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, commas, coordination

- > I have two suits, but I like neither.
- > They were busy, but we weren't.
- > One of his sons is married, and the other isn't.

I was taught that a comma only precedes a coordinating conjunction if an independent clause follows. I can't tell if these are independent clauses. I feel like an additional word is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have two suits. I like neither.
- They were busy. We weren't.
- One of his sons is married. The other isn't.

The second clause in each is certainly terse and requires the first clause in order to maintain its meaning, but each does stand on its own.